# Determine Neighbouring triangle normal without winding

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

I have a game mechanic where the player has the ability to walk on triangles defined in 3D coordinates.My problem is in the event that the player is walking on two triangles that are connected and attempts to walk to the other triangle, how can I determine which triangle face he should be walking on.

For example in the image below, the player is on T1 on the face with the Normal T3. He attempts to walk to T2 with the normal N1. The technique will also need to work when trying to go to N4 to N2

[image: diagram]

The only way I can think of is raycasting around the triangle edge but I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution. Also I should mention that vertex winding can't be used here.

Comment: Why can't vertex winding be used?

Comment: do you have these triangles in some ordered data structure or is this some random mesh? also how does your player "looks" like/behaves? do you want a smooth transition or kind of an instant switch of where "downwards" is? maybe add some code and/or pictures from inside unity.